# Mesclar células Excel via código Delphi

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel

Estou atualizando um antigo sistema feito em Delphi que utiliza uma classe para criar um arquivo Excel sem a necessidade de utilizar objetos OLE ou ter o Excel instalado.

A Classe funciona normalmente utilizando o código que está logo mais abaixo.

Agora surgiu a necessidade de adicionar uma informação na primeira linha, porém, mesclando a quantidade de colunas total do relatório.

Segue a classe

```delphi
unit ExportToExcel;

interface


uses Windows, SysUtils, DB, Math;

// ============================================================
// TDataSet to Excel without OLE or Excel required
// Mike Heydon Dec 2002
// ============================================================

type
  // TDataSetToExcel
  TDataSetToExcel = class(TObject)
  protected
    procedure WriteToken(AToken: word; ALength: word);
    procedure WriteFont(const AFontName: Ansistring; AFontHeight,
      AAttribute: word);
    procedure WriteFormat(const AFormatStr: Ansistring);
  private
    FRow: word;
    FDataFile: file;
    FFileName: string;
    FDataSet: TDataSet;
  public
    constructor Create(ADataSet: TDataSet; const AFileName: string);
    function WriteFile: boolean;
  end;

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation

const
  // XL Tokens
  XL_DIM = $00;
  XL_BOF = $09;
  XL_EOF = $0A;
  XL_DOCUMENT = $10;
  XL_FORMAT = $1E;
  XL_COLWIDTH = $24;
  XL_FONT = $31;

  // XL Cell Types
  XL_INTEGER = $02;
  XL_DOUBLE = $03;
  XL_STRING = $04;

  // XL Cell Formats
  XL_INTFORMAT = $81;
  XL_DBLFORMAT = $82;
  XL_XDTFORMAT = $83;
  XL_DTEFORMAT = $84;
  XL_TMEFORMAT = $85;
  XL_HEADBOLD = $40;
  XL_HEADSHADE = $F8;

  // ========================
  // Create the class
  // ========================

constructor TDataSetToExcel.Create(ADataSet: TDataSet;
  const AFileName: string);
begin
  FDataSet := ADataSet;
  FFileName := ChangeFileExt(AFilename, '.xls');
end;

// ====================================
// Write a Token Descripton Header
// ====================================

procedure TDataSetToExcel.WriteToken(AToken: word; ALength: word);
var
  aTOKBuffer: array[0..1] of word;
begin
  aTOKBuffer[0] := AToken;
  aTOKBuffer[1] := ALength;
  Blockwrite(FDataFile, aTOKBuffer, SizeOf(aTOKBuffer));
end;

// ====================================
// Write the font information
// ====================================

procedure TDataSetToExcel.WriteFont(const AFontName: ansistring;
  AFontHeight, AAttribute: word);
var
  iLen: byte;
begin
  AFontHeight := AFontHeight * 20;
  WriteToken(XL_FONT, 5 + length(AFontName));
  BlockWrite(FDataFile, AFontHeight, 2);
  BlockWrite(FDataFile, AAttribute, 2);
  iLen := length(AFontName);
  BlockWrite(FDataFile, iLen, 1);
  BlockWrite(FDataFile, AFontName[1], iLen);
end;

// ====================================
// Write the format information
// ====================================

procedure TDataSetToExcel.WriteFormat(const AFormatStr: ansistring);
var
  iLen: byte;
begin
  WriteToken(XL_FORMAT, 1 + length(AFormatStr));
  iLen := length(AFormatStr);
  BlockWrite(FDataFile, iLen, 1);
  BlockWrite(FDataFile, AFormatStr[1], iLen);
end;

// ====================================
// Write the XL file from data set
// ====================================

function TDataSetToExcel.WriteFile: boolean;
var
  bRetvar: boolean;
  aDOCBuffer: array[0..1] of word;
  aDIMBuffer: array[0..3] of word;
  aAttributes: array[0..2] of byte;
  i: integer;
  iColNum,
    iDataLen: byte;
  sStrData: string;
  fDblData: double;
  wWidth: word;
  sStrBytes: TBytes;
begin
  bRetvar := true;
  FRow := 0;
  FillChar(aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes), 0);
  AssignFile(FDataFile, FFileName);

  try
    Rewrite(FDataFile, 1);
    // Beginning of File
    WriteToken(XL_BOF, 4);
    aDOCBuffer[0] := 0;
    aDOCBuffer[1] := XL_DOCUMENT;
    Blockwrite(FDataFile, aDOCBuffer, SizeOf(aDOCBuffer));

    // Font Table
    WriteFont('Arial', 10, 0);
    WriteFont('Arial', 10, 1);
    WriteFont('Courier New', 11, 0);

    // Column widths
    for i := 0 to FDataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
      wWidth := (FDataSet.Fields[i].DisplayWidth + 1) * 256;
      if FDataSet.FieldDefs[i].DataType = ftDateTime then
        inc(wWidth, 2000);
      if FDataSet.FieldDefs[i].DataType = ftDate then
        inc(wWidth, 1050);
      if FDataSet.FieldDefs[i].DataType = ftTime then
        inc(wWidth, 100);
      WriteToken(XL_COLWIDTH, 4);
      iColNum := i;
      BlockWrite(FDataFile, iColNum, 1);
      BlockWrite(FDataFile, iColNum, 1);
      BlockWrite(FDataFile, wWidth, 2);
    end;

    // Column Formats
    WriteFormat('General');
    WriteFormat('0');
    WriteFormat('###,###,##0.00');
    WriteFormat('dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss');
    WriteFormat('dd-mmm-yyyy');
    WriteFormat('hh:mm:ss');

    // Dimensions
    WriteToken(XL_DIM, 8);
    aDIMBuffer[0] := 0;
    aDIMBuffer[1] := Min(FDataSet.RecordCount, $FFFF);
    aDIMBuffer[2] := 0;
    aDIMBuffer[3] := Min(FDataSet.FieldCount - 1, $FFFF);
    Blockwrite(FDataFile, aDIMBuffer, SizeOf(aDIMBuffer));

    // Column Headers
    for i := 0 to FDataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
//      sStrData := FDataSet.Fields[i].DisplayName;
      sStrBytes :=
TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(FDataSet.Fields[i].DisplayName);
      iDataLen := length(sStrBytes);
      WriteToken(XL_STRING, iDataLen + 8);
      WriteToken(FRow, i);
      aAttributes[1] := XL_HEADBOLD;
      aAttributes[2] := XL_HEADSHADE;
      BlockWrite(FDataFile, aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes));
      BlockWrite(FDataFile, iDataLen, SizeOf(iDataLen));
      if iDataLen > 0 then
        BlockWrite(FDataFile, sStrBytes[0], iDataLen);
      aAttributes[2] := 0;
    end;

    // Data Rows
    while not FDataSet.Eof do
    begin
      inc(FRow);

      for i := 0 to FDataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
      begin
        case FDataSet.FieldDefs[i].DataType of
          ftBoolean,
            ftWideString,
            ftFixedChar,
            ftString:
            begin
//              sStrData := FDataSet.Fields[i].AsString;

sStrBytes:=TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(FDataSet.Fields[i].AsString);
              iDataLen := length(sStrBytes);
              WriteToken(XL_STRING, iDataLen + 8);
              WriteToken(FRow, i);
              aAttributes[1] := 0;
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes));
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, iDataLen, SizeOf(iDataLen));
              if iDataLen > 0 then
                BlockWrite(FDataFile, sStrBytes[0], iDataLen);
            end;

          ftAutoInc,
            ftSmallInt,
            ftInteger,
            ftWord,
            ftLargeInt:
            begin
              fDblData := FDataSet.Fields[i].AsFloat;
              iDataLen := SizeOf(fDblData);
              WriteToken(XL_DOUBLE, 15);
              WriteToken(FRow, i);
              aAttributes[1] := XL_INTFORMAT;
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes));
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, fDblData, iDatalen);
            end;

          ftFloat,
            ftCurrency,
            ftBcd:
            begin
              fDblData := FDataSet.Fields[i].AsFloat;
              iDataLen := SizeOf(fDblData);
              WriteToken(XL_DOUBLE, 15);
              WriteToken(FRow, i);
              aAttributes[1] := XL_DBLFORMAT;
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes));
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, fDblData, iDatalen);
            end;

          ftDateTime:
            begin
              fDblData := FDataSet.Fields[i].AsFloat;
              iDataLen := SizeOf(fDblData);
              WriteToken(XL_DOUBLE, 15);
              WriteToken(FRow, i);
              aAttributes[1] := XL_XDTFORMAT;
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes));
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, fDblData, iDatalen);
            end;

          ftDate:
            begin
              fDblData := FDataSet.Fields[i].AsFloat;
              iDataLen := SizeOf(fDblData);
              WriteToken(XL_DOUBLE, 15);
              WriteToken(FRow, i);
              aAttributes[1] := XL_DTEFORMAT;
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes));
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, fDblData, iDatalen);
            end;

          ftTime:
            begin
              fDblData := FDataSet.Fields[i].AsFloat;
              iDataLen := SizeOf(fDblData);
              WriteToken(XL_DOUBLE, 15);
              WriteToken(FRow, i);
              aAttributes[1] := XL_TMEFORMAT;
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, aAttributes, SizeOf(aAttributes));
              BlockWrite(FDataFile, fDblData, iDatalen);
            end;

        end;
      end;

      FDataSet.Next;
    end;

    // End of File
    WriteToken(XL_EOF, 0);
    CloseFile(FDataFile);
  except
    bRetvar := false;
  end;

  Result := bRetvar;
end;

end.
```

Segue o que já tentei sem sucesso

```
sStrData := 'A1:A10';
iDataLen := Length(sStrData);
WriteToken(XL_STRING, iDataLEn + 8); // Tentei tbm com XL_FORMAT
WriteToken(0, 1); // Escrevendo no binario do arquivo XLS para informar que a referencia é a Linha 0, Coluna 1;
```

Imagino que eu precise escrever informações no binário do XLS indicando o merge, porém ainda não consegui com esse código.

Não posso mudar radicalmente a forma de gerar esse XLS.
Como o código sugere, preciso escrever uma informação na primeira linha e o arquivo possui 10 colunas. A informação precisa estar nessas l0 colunas mescladas em 1.

Answer (score 3):

A classe utilizada não permite o uso de MERGE de células porque ele gera um XLS no formato do Excel 2.1 que não possui este recurso.

Para que consiga ter células mescladas é necessário que o XLS seja para uma versão superior, que permita esse tipo de recurso, de acordo com o próprio Excel.

Portanto, para gerar uma planilha com os recursos necessários será preciso usar algum componente ou os elementos presentes na própria IDE que fazem uso de OLE.

Eis uma boa lista para começar a testar componentes. 
http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=555&sort=ID